# Java.io.FileNotFoundException for a file that's there

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I am currently creating a err... annoying program that repeatedly plays a ding sound, but there is a error whenever I run it. I have tried everything, and the file IS in the correct spot. Here is my current code:

```
public class PlaySound {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    while (true) {
            String path = PlaySound.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().replaceAll("%20", " ");;
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path + "//src//ding.wav");

            AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);

            AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, I have used other formats of the code like `//src//ding.wav`
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: also the error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\*** ******\Desktop\ding.jar\src\ding.wav (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.lookatthis.PlaySound.main(PlaySound.java:19)
```

EDIT2: The error is older before I renamed the file. I changed the error to reflect the current filename

Comment: Can you please provide the output of System.out.println(path);

Comment: what's the file you're looking for: hit.wav or ding.wav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to read a resource in a `jar` file specifying the absolute path of your hard disk drive.

```
ding.jar\src\hit.wav
```

So there are two alternatives, or unzip your ding.jar file into a directory.
Or specify the relative path and access to the file using the classloader resource reader.

Using the resource reader you can find to the `hit.wav` file using

```
InputStream in = PlaySound.class.getResource("/ding.wav").openStream();
AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
```

Comment: That's because my file names are screwed up so I changed them to make more sense. The error is old lol

Comment: Yeah. Got a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It is in the jar's src file, named ding.wav

Comment: so in the eclipse menu it's in PlaySound/src/ding.wav

Comment: You should place the file `ding.wav` in the same package of class `PlaySound`

Comment: Works in Eclipse. Now I just need to try it built into a jar.

Comment: IT WORKS! THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to unjar your ding.jar to expand its file structure.  FileInputStream (probably?) can't access the jar'ed version of this file.